# Bad Pointers and Garbled Data

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, memory-management

Forgive me if I might sound stupid, but I'm a Bio major student who ended up working in software development (never had a single subject on coding). So coding isn't in my forte, but I really want to learn.

Now that that's out of the way: Pointers.

I'm writing an application in Visual C++ for serial communication and have spent the last three days struggling to output the right data.

This is the relevant code block:

```
//The ports have been opened, data has been written and the  rest follows
//Initialising buffer

DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
BYTE*  abBuffer = NULL; // Instance 1


do
{
    // Read data from the COM-port
    serial2.Read(&abBuffer,sizeof(&abBuffer),&dwBytesRead); // Instance 2
    if (dwBytesRead > 0)
       {
        CString a=(LPCTSTR)&abBuffer;//To check what is being read        
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_RECV,(LPCTSTR)&abBuffer);


}
else
MessageBox("No");
}
while (dwBytesRead == sizeof(&abBuffer));
//delete[] abBuffer; 
//Close the port again
```

While debugging I can see that at Instance 1 "abBuffer" is

abBuffer 0xcccccccc 
unsigned char *

and at Instance 2 it is

abBuffer 0x00000000 
unsigned char *

I know that the value at instance 1 is a mode code used because I put a breakpoint before that line and 2 is NULL, ***but why the bad pointer?***

Also the data I'm receiving is acting weird.

**Try 1:**

Sent data : "hi"

Received data : "hiÜÜÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

**Try 2:**

Sent data : "hihihi"

Received data : "hiÜÜÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

**Try 3:** *To check which end of the data is being cut of*

Sent data : "aibicidi"

Received data : "cidiÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

else clause triggered ***WHY?***

**Try 4:** *To check what the cut off is, turns out it is 4 bytes*

Sent data = "mike"

Received data = "mikeÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

else clause triggered

***Any ideas why my data might be getting garbled?***

There are three main questions, but they are related so that's why I'm here.

Help?

Comment: Set the compiler to warning level 4 and look at all the warnings you get from the compiler. They will give you strong hints where you are doing things wrong. And please read a good book about C++ and pointers and buffers.

Comment: Set it to -w4 and got no warnings. So maybe it is something else? Also any suggestions for a good book? Maybe learning as I go isn't a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems. To start with `abBuffer` is a null pointer. You can not write data to where it's pointing. Secondly, `&abBuffer` gives you a pointer to the *variable* `abBuffer`.

The solution to the first problem is to allocate memory for `abBuffer` to point to. This is simplest done by using an *array* instead of a pointer.

The solution to the second problem is to not use the address-of operator, but plain `abBuffer`.

Comment: He is not reading into *abBuffer but into abBuffer (strange, but true), so it is of no interest if abBuffer is NULL.

Comment: That was my first approach. But since the data being read does not have a fixed size, I cannot declare it's size before hand. Hence I tried referring to its pointer. For example, the receiver port might receive any number of bytes, if that is lower than the size of the array I am writing it into, won't the remaining bytes be filled with something else?

Comment: @MichaelThomas Then there are two possible solution: One is to simply allocate enough to fit any kind of know message, and read message-wise. The other is to read one by at a time, and reallocate/append to the buffer (which will be easier if you use e.g. a `std::vector` instead).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the input, I'm still trying for a way to message go into a variable whose size can be dynamically declared. Any idea why the data is getting garbled? The buffer is supposed to be empty at the beginning of each build.